# Deleting duplicate files

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My problem is, I have this code working (Almost completely perfect), but it creates two of the same file, I assumed it was the FileOutputStream, tried to create a "new File" and put it in its parameter and delete using "file.delete();" after closing it with "save.close();", just like people recommend after so many searchs, but I still keep two files, the only difference is that the files created are empty, with 0kb.

Half the code I copied from a tutorial, the other half I wrote myself, but I still don't fully understand what it does, since I'm not a programmer, and java is not my main programming language.
I hope someone can help me, thank you.

```
public static boolean SetRingtone(Context context, int type, int music) {
        byte[] buffer = null; int size = 0;
        InputStream fIn = context.getResources().openRawResource(music);

        try {
            size = fIn.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            fIn.read(buffer); fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {return false;}

        String folderType = "";
        if (type == RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE) folderType = "ringtones" + File.separator;
        else if (type == RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION) folderType = "notifications" + File.separator;
        else if (type == RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM) folderType = "alarms" + File.separator;

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "media/audio" + File.separator + folderType;
        String filename = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(music) + ".mp3";
        filename = filename.replace("_", " - ");
        String[] artist = filename.split(" - ");

        boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
        if (!exists) {new File(path).mkdirs();}

        try {
            FileOutputStream save;
            save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
            save.write(buffer); save.flush(); save.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {return false;}
        catch (IOException e) {return false;}


        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));

        File f = new File(path, filename);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artist[0]);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, filename);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");

        if (type == RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE) {values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);}
        else if (type == RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION) {values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);}
        else if (type == RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM) {values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);}

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, newUri);
        context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f.getAbsolutePath()), values);
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT: Second version of the code, that creates empty files.

```
FileOutputStream save;
try {
    File j = new File(path, filename);
    save = new FileOutputStream(j);
    save.write(buffer); save.flush(); save.close(); j.delete();
}
```

EDIT 2: Okay, so after a few more tests I realized that the file is only created with 0kb the first time the method runs, if I run it again the file is created normally, but always with two newly created files, with the same name, extension and in the same directory.

Comment: is it come with same name and type?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same file.

Comment: Could you please check what `fIn.available()` returns? The returned value is only an estimate and in case of `0` would imo lead to the 0 KByte files.

Comment: It always returns 98293, I tested with the 2 versions of the code, the one that works, and using a "new File(path, filename)" on FileOutputStream parameters, that creates the empty files.        FileOutputStream save;
  File j;
  try {
   j = new File(path, filename);
   save = new FileOutputStream(j);
   save.write(buffer); save.flush(); save.close(); j.delete();
  }

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by `two of the same file`.

Comment: Instead of creating one file, I get two files with the same name and same extension in the same directory.